# Is this strange IndexOf behaviour intended?

Tags: c#, string

I was investigating a bug and found that a hard coded string defined with a slightly different double quotes (`"` vs `"`) produces the following behavior when calling the [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0) method:

```
Console.WriteLine(":::".IndexOf(":", 2));

Console.WriteLine(":::ؘ".IndexOf(":", 2));
```

The output will be:

```
2
-1
```

(run it [here](https://rextester.com/DGSFYW28296))

After further investigation, it seems that using the different double quotes character when defining the string causes it to have Length "4" instead of "3". The following code:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)":::ؘ".Length);
Console.WriteLine((int)":::ؘ"[0]);
Console.WriteLine((int)":::ؘ"[1]);
Console.WriteLine((int)":::ؘ"[2]);
Console.WriteLine((int)":::ؘ"[3]);
```

Outputs:

```
4
58
58
58
1560
```

(run it [here](https://rextester.com/PMYN36753))

Still, I don't understand why the **IndexOf** would fail to find that last occurence of the colon character.

Is this behavior intended?

Comment: This is not a different quote, this is a Unicode [codepoint U+0618](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0618/index.htm) as the last character of the string. Adding `, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to your `IndexOf` arguments [fixes it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus#behavioral-differences).

Comment: You have a string, extra character in your code. At any rate, your first code block returns *2* for both cases in .NET 6.0.